# archive page for post format video

Tags: php, wordpress, post, post-format

I have created a post format of video and also created a `single-video.php` to display a single video post. 
added following code to `functions.php` include single video page template.

```
function templateForSingleVideo( $template ) {
    if ( is_single() && has_post_format() ) {
        $post_format_template = locate_template( 'single-' . get_post_format() . '.php' );
        if ( $post_format_template ) {
            $template = $post_format_template;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}   
add_filter( 'template_include', 'templateForSingleVideo' );
```

it works perfectly fine. but now I want a page where the posts (post format=video) will be shown from all the categories. Just want to show all the videos..

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks